# Deserialize xml node's attributes to class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-deserialization

I have two classes that look like this:

```
[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlArray("BarResponse")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Bar")]
    public List<Bar> bar {get; set;}
    //some other elements go here.
}

[XmlRoot("Bar")]
public class Bar
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}
    //some other elements go here.
}
```

The xml I'm receiving looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Foo>
    <BarResponse>
        <Bar id="0" />
        <Bar id="1" />
    </BarResponse>
</Foo>
```

When I attempt to deseralize this, I get an instance of the "Foo" class, and bar has one element in it, with all of it's properties null or default. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I might be wrong here but i think json .net does this to xml as well and it is very good library. maybe is a better option.

Comment: try changing `bar` to `Bar` in your `Foo class` (it could be case sensitivity)

Comment: tested, and it works perfectly, with a correct xml (no `<xml>` `</xml>` tag, but just an `<?xml version="1.0"?>` on first line.

Comment: Good catch @RaphaëlAlthaus. My bad there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BilldrTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SerializeDeserializeTest()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Bars.Add(new Bar { Id = 1 });
        foo.Bars.Add(new Bar { Id = 2 });
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Foo));
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, foo);
        }
        string s = stringBuilder.ToString();
        Foo deserialized;
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(s))
        {
            deserialized = (Foo) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(2,deserialized.Bars.Count);
    }
}

[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bars= new List<Bar>();
    }
    [XmlArray("BarResponses")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Bar))]
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    //some other elements go here.
}

[XmlRoot("Bar")]
public class Bar
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    //some other elements go here.
}
```

- You can find info on the use of XmlRoot [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlroot.aspx)
- [ArrayItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlarrayitems.aspx) is used if you expect the array to contain different types

You would get the same result stripping all attributes except for [XmlAttribute("id")], but I guess this is an excerpt from a context where it all is justified.

Comment: Well, this doesn't change anything : if you use the OP's code the same way (serializing and deserializing), just adding a constructor for Foo (bar list initialization), it also works fine...

Comment: But then it changed something?

Comment: I found the problem thanks to this testing. My initial serialization wasn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a default constructor for the `Foo` class that instantiates your `List<Bar>`.

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bar = new List<Bar>();
    }

    [XmlArray("BarResponse")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Bar")]
    public List<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Bar
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}
```

Writes/Reads xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <BarResponse>
    <Bar id="0" />
    <Bar id="1" />
  </BarResponse>
</Foo>
```